# Determining length of a random list being altered

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, variable-assignment

I have a list being accessed randomly within a list, to which I am adding an element. (note that the element has to be inserted randomly inside of the list, i.e. I don't want to insert at the end or start)
For example:

```
myList = [[0, 1, 4, 7],[0, 3, 2, 7]]
toinsert = [5, 6]

for item in toinsert:
    random.choice(myList).insert(random.randint(1,len(`the list that got chosen`)-2), item)
```

I have tried using

```
choicelist = random.choice(myList)
choicelist.insert(randint(1,len(choicelist)))
```

but then I'm not sure how to put that back in where the original list was - considering it's a random list.

I know I could randomly choose an index for `myList` and use that method, but I was looking for a hopefully more Pythonic - and shorter - way of doing so.

Comment: It's still there. You didn't remove it or anything, so you don't need to do anything to put it back.

Comment: wouldn't the choicelist assignment just create a separate (unrelated) variable?

Comment: It makes a new variable, but not a new list. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to make the changes to `choicelist` reflect back in the original list `myList`.

```
choicelist = random.choice(myList)
```

In the above statement, `choicelist` is reference to some random list inside `myList`, i.e `choicelist` is not a new list created by `random.choice`. So any changes you make in `choicelist` will be reflected in the corresponding list in `myList`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it created a reference instead of a new variable. Is there any way to determine when this happens (when assigning a variable creates a new value instead of referencing something)?

Comment: @A.Schutz: Assigning a variable never makes a new object. The cases where an assignment assigns a new object to a variable are those cases where the right-hand-side creates a new object; the assignment itself never creates an object.

Answer (score 0):

you can break down each operation in functions:

```
import random

def insert_at_random_place(elt, seq):
    insert_index = random.randrange(len(seq))
    seq.insert(insert_index, elt)    # the sequence is mutated, there is no need to return it

def insert_elements(elements, seq_of_seq):
    chosen_seq = random.choice(seq_of_seq)
    for elt in elements:
        insert_at_random_place(elt, chosen_seq)
    # the sequence is mutated, there is no need to return it

myList = [[0, 1, 4, 7],[0, 3, 2, 7]]
toinsert = [5, 6]

insert_elements(toinsert, myList)
```